# Changing the array with a variable in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Is it possible to change the array, trough which is looped with an external variable, which gives the array-name as string?

My example loops through the variable name itself.
I guess this is just a syntax-question? Thanks a lot for your help.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li data-array="one">Array One</li>
    <li data-array="two">Array Two</li>
    <li data-array="three">Array Three</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var one = ['One-One','One-Two','One-Three'];
var two = ['Two-One','Two-Two','Two-Three'];
var three = ['Three-One','Three-Two','Three-Three'];

$('li').click(function(){

  var selectedArray = $(this).attr('data-array');

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(selectedArray[i]);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Loeevw51/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing to a variable by having its name as string *can* be done using `eval()`, but if you have reached the point where you need to do this, you should redesign your code.

A much simpler, faster and cleaner solution is to use an object (if that's an option):

```
var arrays =
{
    one: ['One-One','One-Two','One-Three'],
    two: ['Two-One','Two-Two','Two-Three'],
    three: ['Three-One','Three-Two','Three-Three']
};
```

Then you can use `arrays['one']` or `arrays.one` to access its elements.
[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loeevw51/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can access your variables by using the `window` object. That assumes however, that the variables are global variables (as is the case in your example).

Change your loop to the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window[selectedArray].length; i++) {
    console.log(window[selectedArray][i]);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cre0vjk6/

Comment: This only works when the code is directly wrapped in `head` or `body`, which wasn't the case in OP's fiddle.